# Include handlebars partials when they exist based on context in Ghost

Tags: handlebars.js, ghost-blog

I've got a [customized theme for Ghost](https://github.com/jessehouwing/jessehouwingnl-Casper). I nave a guest author once on a while. I'd love the ability to include any number of custom links to the authors page for each author.

I'm aware of the `authors-{{slug}}.hbs` convention I could use to create a complete custom page for each author, but that's a nightmare to maintain.

Instead I was trying to try to include a partial when it exists. According to the handlebars docs the `{{#> partial }}` should work. But that works when I know the exact name of the partial.

I need the name of the partial to be dynamic based on the context. In my case the ghost slug for the author. [According to the handlebar docs I need to pass in a function](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/partials.html#dynamic-partials)...

[image]

I tried a few ways, but `gscan` dislikes all of them:

```
 {{#> (concat "partials/socials-" slug) }}
 {{#> (concat "partials/socials-" (lookup . 'slug')) }}
 {{#> concat "partials/socials-" (lookup . 'slug') }}
 {{#> "partials/socials-{{slug}}" }}
 {{#> partials/socials-{{slug}} }}
```

All give me:

```
Checking theme compatibility...

Your theme has 1 error!
----

Errors
------
Important to fix, functionality may be degraded.

- Error: Templates must contain valid Handlebars
Files: author.hbs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you used content blocks before? They're a way to re-use template code but still allow for customisation, it's a method used in Casper which you've forked from. Check out these lines here in `page.hbs`: https://github.com/jessehouwing/jessehouwingnl-Casper/blob/customized/page.hbs#L58-L65

as well as this line shown in `default.hbs`: https://github.com/jessehouwing/jessehouwingnl-Casper/blob/customized/default.hbs#L127

What you could do is create a custom author template that inherits the existing `author.hbs` template. For this example I'm going to create a custom author page for the author 'ghost' by creating `author-ghost.hbs`:

```
{{!< author}}

{{#contentFor "links"}}
  <ul>
    <li><a href="https://example.com">Example link</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://example.com">Example link</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://example.com">Example link</a></li>
  </ul>
{{/contentFor}}
```

The above code inherits `author.hbs` and creates a block called `links`. Then in the original `author.hbs` template we can add the block reference to where we want the contents of the block to appear:

```
{{{block "links"}}}
```

Not only will this insert the code in the custom author template, but it'll also gracefully fallback to no output if there isn't a custom author template for the author.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Did you try restarting Ghost?

Comment: Oh, in that case send us a message on our support and I can take a look at the theme :)

Comment: I just modified the block of code for `author-{{slug}}.hbs`, it references the template that should be inherited which is `default-author.hbs`. You'll need to duplicate `author.hbs`, rename it to `default-author.hbs` and add in the `{{{block "links"}}}` where you want the links to appear

Comment: See: https://github.com/jessehouwing/jessehouwingnl-Casper/commit/36ef2cee45a1549f445a9e8919cc543ac2917eed

Comment: Any idea why https://jessehouwing.net/author/sofie/ is now returning 500?! And https://jessehouwing.net/author/jesse-houwing/ may randomly be returning blank pages?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and here how I solved. Just use the lookup in this syntax.

```
  {{#foreach navigation}}
    <li class="nav-{{slug}}">
      <a href="{{url}}" class="social-link" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
       {{>(lookup . 'slug')}}
     </a>
    </li>
  {{/foreach}}
```